# Getting spans for a SpanNear query?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to get the words surrounding a match in a SpanNearQuery but I am not able to figure out how to. I know there is this function called `GetSpans` documented [here](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d2/dc9/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_spans_1_1_span_near_query.html#a0defb19018dd81bbc00a4a254d8bf48a):

```
  129         public override Spans GetSpans(IndexReader reader)
  130         {
  131             if (clauses.Count == 0)
  132             // optimize 0-clause case
  133                 return new SpanOrQuery(GetClauses()).GetSpans(reader);
  134             
  135             if (clauses.Count == 1)
  136             // optimize 1-clause case
  137                 return clauses[0].GetSpans(reader);
  138             
  139             return inOrder?(Spans) new NearSpansOrdered(this, reader, collectPayloads):(Spans) new NearSpansUnordered(this, reader);
  140         }
```

Is this the function I am supposed to use (because it does return a list/array of spans but a single span) or is there some other function?

For instance, if my text is: `lucene is very powerful` and my search term is `lucene powerful`, I want to retrieve the words in the match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to access the adjacent words, you will need to store TermVectors with position and offset information at indexing time, which you can then use to retrieve the surrounding words.

See http://searchhub.org/2009/05/26/accessing-words-around-a-positional-match-in-lucene/ for a detailed explanation.